# How to join 2 tables in MySQL on 2 IDs

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT dispositions.name as disposition_name,leads.first_name,leads.city,leads.province_state,leads.country
FROM leads
LEFT JOIN dispositions ON leads.disposition_id_1=dispositions.id
```

This query joins 2 tables (`leads` and `dispositions`) on the field `disposition_id_1`.
 This works fine and shows me my results.

The problem is that I have a second field in my `leads` table called `disposition_id_2` that joins with my `dispositions` table exactly like the field `disposition_id_1`. So both of these fields are related to the same table and joined by ID.

So how can I join the leads table with the dispositions table on this second field (`disposition_id_2`) considering it's already joined on the same table with the field `disposition_id_1`?

Answer (score 1):

You can join multiple fields with the same id, it wouldn't matter.

```
SELECT dispositions.name 
as 
disposition_name,
leads.first_name,
leads.city,
leads.province_state,
leads.country 
FROM 
leads 
LEFT JOIN 
dispositions 
ON leads.disposition_id_1=dispositions.id
AND leads.disposition_id_2=dispositions.id
```

Here it will get all records where both id_1 and id_2 are equal to dispositions.id. If you just need to match either fields use `OR` instead of `AND`

Comment: Ok - but is "disposition.name" going to the value of disposition_id_1 or disposition_id_2?

Comment: there will be only one `disposition.name` (assuming it is disposition.name and not disposition_name), and that will go to the value of `dispositions.id` `NOT lead.disposition_id_*`

Answer (score 0):

You can join tables multiple times with aliases:

```
SELECT somefield, t1.x, t2.x
FROM ...
JOIN othertable AS t1 ON ...
JOIN othertable AS t2 ON ...
```